# home.xhtml suddenly stopped working after adding new blank .xhtml file

Tags: jsf, primefaces

After adding blank new .xhtml file my webb app stopped working, I didn't change anything in code. After deleting newly created file problem still exist, I got this error at start:

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /integration-webapp/home.xhtml. Reason:

    Not Found
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: done it many times, I also restarted server

Comment: yea, I use netbeans, I just build my projects and copy war to deploy folder in apache servicemix http://scr.hu/98oj/oeskq

Comment: yes it does, what's the problem..